# Breaking bonds with energy

Tags: bond

I'm learning about breaking molecular bonds currently and I'm wondering what are the methods to actually use the amount of bond energy to break the bond. What I'm saying is, knowing the bond energy, how can you actually use this information to break the bond? Do you heat it up the equivalent amount as the Kj/mol or something similar to that?

Comment: I guess you deleted earlier question and reposted it... Never do such thing!

Comment: Sorry I really need the question to be answered

Comment: It's stupid, simply editing it bumps it to the top and could actually improve it.

Comment: I'm new here. I didn't know that

Comment: At least now you'll know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the energy showed that is needed to break bonds is usually in the form of heat. I don't believe there is another common way to do it, but don't quote me on it. I haven't learned about lasers and other such technologies :). Keep in mind that as bonds are broken, they release energy themselves. As bonds are created, they take in energy on their own. Often, you will just need to start a reaction with some outside energy source (A bunsen burner for example) and it will be able to continue on its own because it produces energy from breaking bonds. If you look at the formation of Magnesium Oxide, all you really have to do is light a small end of a piece of Magnesium ribbon, and the whole thing burns because it creates energy as it reacts. I hope that helps!